# spring mvc validation best practices

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am learning myself Spring MVC 2.5 mostly from the docs. Can someone explain the following:

- Advantages/differences of using `command` objects versus using `@ModelAttribute` to pass in the object.
- Is there an easier way to do validation other then writing a Validator object?

Also, in this code how does the line `ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");` work? How can it check if the name is empty on the **person** object when the person object is not passed in?

```
   public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if (p.getAge() < 0) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "negativevalue");
        } else if (p.getAge() > 110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
    }
```

(this code is from section 5.2 from [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html))

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer of your first question.
[http://chompingatbits.com/2009/08/25/spring-formtag-commandname-vs-modelattribute/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103233632/http://chompingatbits.com/2009/08/25/spring-formtag-commandname-vs-modelattribute/)

according to my experience there isn't easier way to fullfill validation, because it's easy enough. You can get it easier integrating libraries such as commons-validator into your project and use pre-defined validation rules in your forms.

[http://numberformat.wordpress.com/tag/spring-mvc-validation/](https://web.archive.org/web/20141017154054/http://numberformat.wordpress.com/tag/spring-mvc-validation/)

and also with 3rd version of Spring you can use Bean validation using annotations.

Comment: nice. so commandName is something old that i dont care about.

Answer (score 3):

- The question about command object is not very clear. If you mean the following syntax

  ```
  @RequestMapping(...) public ModelAndView foo(Command c) { ... }
  ```

  then it is the same as the following

  ```
  @RequestMapping(...) public ModelAndView foo(@ModelAttribute Command c) { ... }
  ```

  because `@ModelAttribute` can be omitted. The only case when it's actually needed is then you need to specify attribute name explicitly (otherwise it would be inferred as a class name with the first letter decapitalized, i.e. `command`)
- In Spring 2.5 - no. In Spring 3.0 you can use [declarative validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) with JSR-303 Bean Validation API.
- The `Errors` object has a reference to the object being validated.

Comment: I guess my understanding of command object isnt clear. I thought that with @ModelAttribute you could annotate an object that will contain properties found in the form, and those properties will be set for you. for example @ModelAttribute User user would give you a prepopulated user object from the registration form. This is what i want to do. But whats the point of the Command object?

Comment: @mkoryak: I used the name `Command` as a placeholder for your own object, such as `User` in your example.